# heroku node js listen in same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I only understand node js a little. I am making a server for a game in web. listen code already in network.js(function server). but in Heroku it needs to listen on index.js or the app will crash... I already search in google how to fix this problem but I didn't get it

please help me :)

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

var WORLD_SX = 128;
var WORLD_SY = 128;
var WORLD_SZ = 32;
var WORLD_GROUNDHEIGHT = 16;
var SECONDS_BETWEEN_SAVES = 60;
var ADMIN_IP = "127.0.0.1";

// Load modules
var modules = {};
modules.helpers = require( "./js/helpers.js" );
modules.blocks = require( "./js/blocks.js" );
modules.world = require( "./js/world.js" );
modules.network = require( "./js/network.js" );
modules.io = require( "socket.io" );
modules.fs = require( "fs" );
var log = require( "util" ).log;

// Set-up evil globals
global.Vector = modules.helpers.Vector;
global.BLOCK = modules.blocks.BLOCK;

// Create new empty world or load one from file
var world = new modules.world.World( WORLD_SX, WORLD_SY, WORLD_SZ );
```

**network.js**

```js
...
function Server( socketio, slots )
{
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    app.use(express.static('.'));

    var io = this.io = socketio(http);
    var s = this;

    io.sockets.on( "connection", function( socket ) { s.onConnection( socket ); } );

    this.eventHandlers = {};
    this.activeNicknames = {};
    this.activeAddresses = {};

    this.maxSlots = slots;
    this.usedSlots = 0;

    this.oneUserPerIp = true;

    http.listen(5000, function() {});
}
```

Comment: You can't have two processes listening on the same port. You either need to put them on different port numbers, combine them into a single application, or have something running in front of them to route traffic.

Comment: well if i want to make it only in 1 port, how? any solution

Comment: If you want to make your applications available from a single port, you will either have to merge their code together as Arkerone suggested, or run them on 5001 and 5002 with a separate application on 5000 that proxies the traffic. There's no way around that - a port can only have one listener.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the port 5000 either in the file index.js or in the file network.js. It's not possible to have two app listening on the same port.

Comment: well if i want to make it only in 1 port, how? any solution